# 3 Quicksorts Functions - Why is the lambda version slower? Code provided

Tags: python, algorithm, lambda, runtime, big-o

I was testing quicksort runtimes and I noticed the lambda version of quicksort was slower.

Why is the lambda version noticeably slower? I've tried swapping the orders that I call each and it seems to stay constantly slower. Is it because I am redeclaring left, equal, and right for each time since filter has to be assigned (versus appending/in place)?

```
import timeit

def qsort(list):
    if len(list) > 1:
        pivot = list[0]
        left = filter(lambda x: x < pivot, list)
        equal = filter(lambda x: x == pivot, list)
        right = filter(lambda x: x > pivot, list)
        return qsort(left) + equal + qsort(right)
    else:
        return list

def sort(array):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    if len(array) > 1:
        pivot = array[0]
        for x in array:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            elif x == pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            elif x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
        return sort(less)+equal+sort(greater)
    else:
        return array

def partition(array, begin, end):
    pivot = begin
    for i in xrange(begin+1, end+1):
        if array[i] <= array[begin]:
            pivot += 1
            array[i], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[i]
    array[pivot], array[begin] = array[begin], array[pivot]
    return pivot

def quicksort(array, begin=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(array) - 1
    if begin >= end:
        return
    pivot = partition(array, begin, end)
    quicksort(array, begin, pivot-1)
    quicksort(array, pivot+1, end)
    return array

print qsort([5,3,1,5,2,6])
print sort([5,3,1,5,2,6])
print quicksort([5,3,1,5,2,6])
print (timeit.timeit(lambda: qsort([5,3,1,5,2,6]), number=1000))
print (timeit.timeit(lambda: sort([5,3,1,5,2,6]), number=1000))
print (timeit.timeit(lambda: quicksort([5,3,1,5,2,6]), number=1000))
```

Comment: You show no evidence that it is so...

Comment: Because extra function calls are expensive relative to inline computations.

Comment: `filter(lambda ... )` should be replaced with a list comprehension `[ i for i in thelist if i < pivot ]`

Comment: Your filter-with-`lambda` version also makes redundant passes over the input.

Comment: User-defined functions are slow; you'll notice a bit of a speed-up if you replace them with built-in functions; e.g., replace `lambda x : x < pivot` with `pivot.__gt__`. (Requires Python 3, however, since in the comparison operators are supplied a bit differently in Python 2.)

Comment: Since there is a claim about speed without any hard numbers to compare, I took the liberty of running the timing myself. `qsort: .011620`, `sort: .005975`, `quicksort: .005509`. The latter 2 are consistently twice as fast as `qsort`, and `quicksort` is consistently faster than `sort`, but by a very small margin. Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Also, if you add `list.sort()` into the mix, it's 10x faster (.000583) than this implementation for `quicksort`. Food for thought. YMMV with different lists than the small example one.

Comment: I don't think the behaviour for 5 elements is very interesting or crucial. You should investigate it for bigger number of elements - maybe around 10^6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the `lambdas` require an extra function call that is expensive. This function could be rewritten using list comprehensions to provide a time that is very close (sometimes smaller) than the other functions.

```
def qsort(ls):
    if len(ls) > 1:
        pivot = ls[0]
        left = [e for e in ls if e < pivot]
        equal = [e for e in ls if e == pivot]
        right = [e for e in ls if e > pivot]
        return qsort(left) + equal + qsort(right)
    else:
        return ls
```

Also, I changed `list` to `ls` so that the built-in `list` isn't shadowed. The really interesting part is that, despite the repeated iteration over the input, and the creation of new intermediate arrays, this is still comparable in time to the in-place sorting function. Unfortunately, I don't know enough to explain why. For larger lists, it seems like `qsort` performs the best and the in-place method starts slowing down significantly.